# Xcode Time Profiler's detail panel shows that "main" is the reason for app's sluggishness, without showing separate method calls inside it.

Tags: arrays, xcode, xcode-instruments

I have created a demo app that applies multiple filters to an image (it is inside the project) and shows buttons in a `UIScrollView` with that images set as a background image. So, all the logic happens in a method that is called right from `viewDidLoad`. I'm not using any threading mechanism, so all the work is happening on the main thread. 
I'm using `Instruments`, specifically `Time Profiler` to find out why the app launches so slow (it is obvious, but I would like to see it in `Time Profiler`).

When I run it I get the following result in the detail panel (in the root):

[image]

And when I press the arrow to see the actual code I get the following:
[image]

And this is for every filter operation.

Shouldn't the panel show the actual method inside of which I do filtering?

Comment: Is the main listing the only one in the call tree?

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk, it is the only one which consumes most of the resources. I just select a separate part of the graph with the highest pick and for that part the 95.5% (in the example above) is consumed only by `main`. When I tap the arrow to see methods it shows only `main`, when I double tap on it the result is like on the second image above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` function is not the cause of your app being slow. In your screenshot the listing for `main` says you spent 0 seconds in `main`.

The Time Profiler instrument records the call stack 1000 times per second. The `main` function is the starting point for your app. That means `main` is going to be on the call stack most of the time your app is running, even though your app is not in `main` most of that time. The `main` function being on the call stack is the reason for the 649 ms and 95.5% listings in your screenshot.

Do not worry about the listing for the `main` function. You have no control over `main`.

If you want to find your functions in the call tree, select the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes. Selecting those checkboxes makes it easier to find your code in the call tree.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've tried using those filters. I haven't used time profiler a lot before, so that's why I asked this question. Anyway, thank you for the explanation. I am wondering about `main` because when selecting a part of a graph which shows high usage of CPU, the highest numbers are usually in front of it.